# Large PDF file not opening in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

I am saving the pdf files as base64 in database on user action.
At some point I need to open the file in new tab which the file is encoded as base64.I'm using the below code.

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+data);
```

It is working fine for files, size less than 1.5MB, i'm able to open those files in new tab.
But for files greater than 1.5MB this is not working, it's opening blank tab.

I'm not sure why it is not working. Is there any workaround

Comment: for the large files, do you see what is in the `data` variable? because it may be a server configuration problem

Comment: @Edwin , data is byte stream of file, only for larger byte url it's not working

Answer (score -1):

Convert base64 pdf string to Bolb and create the object URL. for example:

```
   var file = new Blob([Buffer.from(body.content,'base64')], {type: 'application/pdf'});
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL);
```

Comment: You can't covert base64 encoded data to a Blob like that.

Comment: Please use Buffer.from(body.content, 'base64'), I have updated the previous code, try this one.

Comment: That doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: This is working in reactjs 10.15 and 14.19, reactjs run in browser.